# How to install glibc version that corresponds to GCC 4.4 on RHEL5

Tags: rhel, glibc

We have a program with executables built on RHEL6 using GCC4.4 and we need to run it on RHEL5.5. But RHEL5.5, by default does not have the necessary version of glibc.

Has anyone faced such an issue and possibly recommend how to install their libraries in this particular case?

Comment: The GCC project's FAQ on the subject: https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple

Comment: Also covered a bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448457/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-gcc

Answer (score 1):

This question discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880830/centos-5-8-with-gcc-4-4-7-links-against-libstdc-6-0-8-how-is-it-possible has given me a key to resolution. There are standard packages gcc44 and gcc44-c++ exist for RHEL5.

Comment: Please solicit a fix with the vendor of the binary, so that packing properly requests the library you need.  This is a fundamental part of packaging software properly, and a seamless install using proper tools should be a trivial feature -- the lack of which should be alarming!

RPM as a format is maligned so often (usually due to self-inflicted dependency issues) that we should work to require packages be built properly and not ruin the experience.